# This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

Tags: php, xml, rss, dreamweaver

Trying to work on a website using Dreamweaver and PHP for development.

On the live site, I suddenly found this error:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>
ABCDED
</title>
<cf:treatAs xmlns:cf="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/rss/core/2005">list</cf:treatAs>
<link>http://events.sjsu.edu/default.aspx</link>
<description>RSS Feed ABCD Events Calendar</description>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: You have opened RSS channel...

Comment: What original content? It's an RSS feed. It's designed for viewing with an RSS viewer, not a web browser.

Comment: This is not an error. This is an information message for you that the XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. Why do you think this is an error?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, are are echoing a XML file into a PHP page ?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('URL');
  foreach ($xml->channel->channel as $value){ 
    $var1 = $value->link;
    $var2 = $value->description;
} 
echo $var1."<br>".$var2;
```

Display it in php.

Hope it works!

Comment: My issue is that the Page which is supposed to be displayed, doesnt get displayed. Instead, this RSS feed shows up. How do I correct that?

Comment: @Anan wats the url you are opening ? or displaying ?